Square of an Incidence matrix.
A problem at the end of my D syllabus textbook asks me to interpret the entries of the product of an Incidence Matrix with itself.
It's an elementary level question but I have failed to find any interpretation of the question except the one given by solution manual which is completely lost on me. 
Here is it's solution as per the manual:


just part(b). I understand the Incidence matrix given and what it represents but not its self product and how can the resultant product's entries be interpreted?

Why images should not be used to explain a math problem

@AmrutAyan, I have never heard of these terms (in-degree and out-degree) before. Mind you, this is an elementary-level book and nowhere the reference to such terms were given.

with apologies, I couldn't see exactly how in/out degrees are represented in the said matrix. I cannot find a consistent pattern either in a column or a row, possibly representing a vertex, representing this phenomenon. This chapter is named Introduction to Matrices, and I am not studying graph theory formally.

HINT: The entry $m_{i,j}$ of the incidence matrix $M$ is the number of direct flights (or whatever) from city $i$ to city $j$. So what is the meaning of the $i$-$j$ entry of $M^2$, which is of course $\sum_{k=1}^4 m_{i,k} m_{k,j}$?

@PaulTanenbaum No. The Incidence matrix M  is interpreted row by row where each row corresponds to a city where a flight originates from and each column shows where it ends. It just shows whether a flight from a particular city, represented by a complete row, to a particular city, represented by a column, exists or not i.e. 0/1, Not the number of direct flights

That is an unimportant detail, but I’ll modify my previous assertion: $m_{i,j} = \mbox{sgn}(\mbox{the number of direct flights from $i$ to $j$})$. The point of my hint remains the same. Consider what the dot product  of (the transpose of) $M$’s $i$th row and its $j$th column is telling you under this interpretation.

@PaulTanenbaum you lost me. And what's the deal with transpose? Is it the dot product of a matrix with its transpose and why so?
